# The responsiveness disappears when I connect my page to a new domain

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

I have just finished an education in web development. When I studied did I get repos from school but when I did my final project did I get help to do a repo from scratch in Github.
I bought a domain (.se) to my final project, but when I connected my page I got at netlify.app the pages responsiveness disappeared. The page borjebrorson.netlify.app works perfectly in laptop, tablet and mobile, but when I connect it to borjebrorson.se the responsiveness for tablet and mobile disappears.

I tried to connect another repo to my .se (a repo I got from school) and then the responsiveness did work, so it is something with my repo I did from scratch that doesn’t work. Someone said it could be something with the stylesheet, I have compared my stylesheet to the repo that did work and I can’t see what’s the different between the two pages.

I have understood that this line is important, and I do have it in the stylesheet.

Anyone that can figure out why the responsiveness disappears for me?

Link to my repo [https://github.com/LovisaBrorson/final-project]

Comment: Your website at borjebrorson.se is fully responsive if I open it (except of some menu items not fitting into the menu / breaking into a second line due to too little space on tablet sizes) - maybe you just have a caching problem (?)

Comment: It is supposed to be a hamburger menu in tablet and mobile view. And under Gallery will you only see one painting at the time, now, in laptop view, you can see two in a row ect.